# Posting an answer results in a 404 page when using Chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro, answers, posting

So I've typed in my answer, press post, and BAM: 404 Page. Go back (copy my answer) and refresh, the question is there. Try again, BAM: 404 Page.

Here is the question : [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272494/sort-a-csv-file-by-last-name-with-php`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272494/sort-a-csv-file-by-last-name-with-php)

Here is the 404 URL: [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272494/answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272494/answer)

I also had to switch to Firefox to Post this Question. So I believe it is a bug in Chrome.

I asked it here: [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Posted to Here: [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/post`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/post) 
which ended up to be just a blank Ask Form.

**Edit:** Using Chrome 3.0.

Comment: I just tried in Safari and I was able to post... maybe you hit a deployment issue?

Comment: We'll, I've been able to reproduce it like 10 times already, so I don't think they are deploying something.

Comment: I am also unable to logout....

Comment: Seems like any 'POST' related forms aren't working for some reason.

Comment: Wow ... Guide To Using Windows: 1) Always Restart the Application. It works now lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posted and deleted my answer there with no problem in Chrome 2.0.

Comment: I'm using 3.0, not 2.0. Which might be the problem, because I believe it is beta.

Comment: I cannot believe that I just had to restart Chrome.

Comment: Sometimes if Chrome has been updated but not restarted, you can get some weird results.

Answer (score 1):

I use Chrome on Linux (dev channel) and three different Windows boxes (1 dev, 2 stable) all day long. I'd notice if it were reliably broken...